# Send e-mail form and continue on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, email

I can send email and get normally , but would like to click the submit button , the form was sent and presented a message to the user and continue on the page normally ... Ja tried with ajax and everything and nothing.

I would like the message to appear in a div , identical to the image below.

**html**

```
<form class="well form-horizontal" action="php/contato.php" method="post" id="contact_form">
    <fieldset>

            <legend style="text-align: center;">Fale conosco</legend>

        <!-- Nome -->

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Nome</label>
            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                    <input name="name" placeholder="Nome Completo" class="form-control" type="text" required>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Email-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail</label>
            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                    <input name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" class="form-control" type="text" required>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- Telefone-->

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Telefones</label>
            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
                    <input name="telefone" placeholder="(xx)xxxxx-xxxx" class="form-control" type="text" required> </br>
                    <input name="celular" placeholder="Seu Whatsapp (Opcional)" class="form-control" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Assunto-->

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Assunto</label>
            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i></span>
                    <input name="assunto" placeholder="Assunto" class="form-control" type="text" required>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Mensagem -->

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Deixe-nos sua mensagem.</label>
            <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="mensagem" placeholder="Dúvidas, elogios, Criticas ou Sugestões são bem vindas." required></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        **<!-- I want the message to appear here -->**
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success_message">Sucesso <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> Muito obrigado pelo contato, retornaremos em breve.</div>

        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Enviar  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
   $(function () {

    $('#contact_form').validator();

    $('#contact_form').on('submit', function (e) {
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "php/contato.php";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data)
                {
                    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                    var messageText = data.message;

                    var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                        $('#contact_form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                        $('#contact_form')[0].reset();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

**contato.php**

```
    <?php

// configure
$from = 'email';
$sendTo = 'email';
$subject = 'Contato do site';
$fields = array('name' => 'Nome do Cliente', 'email' => 'Email', 'telefone' => 'Telefone', 'celular' => 'Celular', 'assunto' => 'Assunto', 'mensagem' => 'Mensagem'); // array variable name => Text to appear in email
$okMessage = 'Email enviado, já já entraremos em contato';
$errorMessage = 'Ocorreu um erro no envio e ja fomos notificados sobre isso, aperte F5 e tente novamente por favor';

// let's do the sending

try
{
    $emailText = "Mais um contato chegando através do site\n=============================\n";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }

    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, "From: " . $from);

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
 ?>
```

[image: send email]

Comment: Ajax to the Rescue...

Comment: impossible to test without knowing which plugin used for `validator()`. So, check for errors and look at your console. No idea also if jquery's loaded or not.

Answer (score 2):

```
...
$('#contact_form').on('submit', function (e) {
    if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
...
```

You're not preventing the default action.

You probably want to use:

```
...
$('#contact_form').on('submit', function (e) {
    // Prevent form submission
    e.preventDefault();
    if (true) { // you no longer need the if-block
...
```

Comment: only this change sent the form and will cause the user stays on the same page ?

Comment: a form's default action on submit is to reload the page, so yes, you want to prevent the default action and instead execute your AJAX call. You can test it by setting the form's action to a different url than your AJAX call's url and check which one gets accessed.

Comment: Altered and published and beyond not work because redirected to the page of contato.php the email was not fired for there came nothing in the inbox :( Can you tell me why ?

Comment: Like I said, for testing you could set the `action="php/contato.php"` to a different url than `var url = "php/contato.php";` also make sure your site is properly reloaded and not cached. As for no content being posted, you should check if you can access `this` in the `ajax()` scope. For testing you should use `data: $('#contact_form').serialize(),` just to be sure.

Comment: @PauloRoberto This should have worked as I tested it just now. Check your console as I said up there in comments and for errors on php and if jquery is loaded. I had to comment out this line `$('#contact_form').validator();` because there are too many plugins out there that use the same function name. You also need to remove `action="php/contato.php"` which is another main issue here.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
    <form class="well form-horizontal" action="" method="POST" id="contact_form">
        <fieldset>

            <legend style="text-align: center;">Fale conosco</legend>

            <!-- Nome -->

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Nome</label>
                <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                        <input name="name" placeholder="Nome Completo" class="form-control" type="text" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Email-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail</label>
                <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                        <input name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" class="form-control" type="text" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <!-- Telefone-->

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Telefones</label>
                <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
                        <input name="telefone" placeholder="(xx)xxxxx-xxxx" class="form-control" type="text" required> </br>
                        <input name="celular" placeholder="Seu Whatsapp (Opcional)" class="form-control" type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Assunto-->

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Assunto</label>
                <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i></span>
                        <input name="assunto" placeholder="Assunto" class="form-control" type="text" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Mensagem -->

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Deixe-nos sua mensagem.</label>
                <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="mensagem" placeholder="Dúvidas, elogios, Criticas ou Sugestões são bem vindas." required></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- I want the message to appear here -->
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success_message">
                Sucesso <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> Muito obrigado pelo contato, retornaremos em breve.
            </div>

            <!-- Button -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Enviar  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function ($) {
            $(document).ready(function (e) {
                var contactForm = $('#contact_form');
                contactForm.on('submit', function (evt) {
                    evt.preventDefault();
                    var url     = "contato.php";
                    var objData = {
                        "name"      : $("input[name=name]").val(),
                        "email"     : $("input[name=email]").val(),
                        "telefone"  : $("input[name=telefone]").val(),
                        "celular"   : $("input[name=celular]").val(),
                        "assunto"   : $("input[name=assunto]").val(),
                        "mensagem"  : $("input[name=mensagem]").val()
                    };

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: url,
                        data: objData,
                        success: function (data){
                            if (data.type && data.message) {
                                var messageAlert    = 'alert-' + data.type;
                                var messageText     = data.message;
                                var alertBox        = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable">';
                                alertBox           += '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>';
                                alertBox           += messageText + '</div>';
                                contactForm.find('#success_message').html(alertBox);
                                contactForm[0].reset();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                })
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

**PHP**

```
    <?php
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
        header('Content-Type: application/json');

        // PLEASE MAKE SURE YOU DON'T HAVE ANY WHITESPACE BEFORE THE OPENING PHP TAG (<?php)
        // Por favor, certifique-se de que você não tem qualquer espaço em branco antes da tag de abertura do PHP ( <?php )
        $from           = 'email';
        $sendTo         = 'email';
        $subject        = 'Contato do site';
        $okMessage      = 'Email enviado, já já entraremos em contato';
        $errorMessage   = 'Ocorreu um erro no envio e ja fomos notificados sobre isso, aperte F5 e tente novamente por favor';


        try {

            // GET  & SANITIZE THE POST DATA...
            $name       = isset($_POST['name'])     ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['name']))        : "";
            $email      = isset($_POST['email'])    ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email']))       : "";
            $telefone   = isset($_POST['telefone']) ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['telefone']))    : "";
            $celular    = isset($_POST['celular'])  ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['celular']))     : "";
            $assunto    = isset($_POST['assunto'])  ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['assunto']))     : "";
            $mensagem   = isset($_POST['mensagem']) ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['mensagem']))    : "";

            // BUILD UP THE MESSAGE...
            $emailText  = "Mais um contato chegando através do site\n=============================\n";
            $emailText .= "Nome do Cliente: \n$name\n\n";
            $emailText .= "Email: \n$email\n\n";
            $emailText .= "Telefone: \n$telefone\n\n";
            $emailText .= "Celular: \n$celular\n\n";
            $emailText .= "Assunto: \n$assunto\n\n";
            $emailText .= "Mensagem: \n$mensagem\n\n";

            mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, "From: " . $from);

            $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
        }catch (\Exception $e){
            $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
        }

        // SIMPLY DIE-OUT THE JSON-ENCODED RESPONSE...
        die(json_encode($responseArray));
    ?>
```

Comment: I tested this code and submit after the user is redirected to the page and appears contato.php this data on the screen { "type": "success" , "message": " Email sent , j \ u00e1 j \ u00e1 will contact "}

Comment: @PauloRoberto  Check it now... it should work...  you should copy also the HTML because we updated it too... to test it; just copy all: **HTML, JAVASCRIPT & PHP.**  Good-Luck to you, my Friend.....

Comment: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin is therefore not allowed access.